# Where to set SetDefaultViewModelFactory in Prism 7.2

Tags: prism

Where in App.xaml.cs should one make a call to ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory?

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory((type) =>
{
    return Container.Resolve(type);
});
```

Should it be done in ConfigureViewModelLocator or somewhere else?  In ConfigureViewModelLocator the Container is still null.

Is it best to use a container as the view model factory or use the default behavior of Activator.CreateInstance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should it be done in `ConfigureViewModelLocator`?

Yes.

> In ConfigureViewModelLocator the Container is still null.

That does not matter, the configured factory is not called until the first view model is resolved which will be definitely after initializing the container...

> Is it best to use a container as the view model factory?

Sure, otherwise your view models will be unable to receive dependencies.